# StDev() function returns Null when table contains only one row

Tags: sql, ms-access, standard-deviation

I am trying to use the StDev function and am getting blank results. I am using it as...

```
SELECT StDev(fldMean) FROM myTable
```

Where fldMean contains a value of 2.3 and should evaluate to 0 but instead I am simply getting an empty result. I can't seem to understand how expressions are to be used in the function, Microsoft's manual really didn't help.

Comment: what is the datatype of fldMean? your query is correct, either there is a problem with the type or StDev doesn't work if there's only 1 row

Comment: How many rows does [myTable] have?

Comment: That is the problem, narrowed my data set down to the point where I only had one row.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT StDev(fldMean) FROM myTable
```

will return `Null` if [myTable] has only one row because the Standard Deviation cannot be computed from a single observation. You will need at least two rows in that table before you can receive a meaningful result. If you want to force the `Null` value to zero you can use

```
SELECT Nz(StDev(fldMean), 0) FROM myTable
```