# Getting "Null" values for Aggregating the Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I writing a query and getting the value

I have tried this on SQL Server 2012

```
;With CTE_ColorIndicator
AS
(
    select Name,Value,Report_Date,
    Dense_Rank() Over(Order by Report_Date DESC)Dno,
    (AVG(value)+(3*STDEV(value))) UpperLimit,
    (AVG(value)+(3*STDEV(value)))*0.85 Limit 
    from #Temp1 
    group by Name,value,Report_date
)

Select * 
from CTE_ColorIndicator 
where Dno <=90 and Dno > 7
```

"I expected the aggregated values in the place of Upper-limit and limit columns"
"But the output is showing 'NULL' values in the upper-limit and limit columns"

Comment: Maybe `STDEV(value)` is null?

Comment: Yes STDEV(value) is null how to overcome this... i mean how to get STDEV aggregated values.

Comment: Purpose of using DENSE_RANK is not that clear. Can you please explain with adding some sample and expected output data?

Comment: The query is aggregating the single value. Try `select stdev(10)`

Comment: Use `COALESCE(STDEV(value), 0`. There is no deviation if `STDEV` is applied to just one value.

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937087/stdev-function-returns-null-when-table-contains-only-one-row, you can't calculate STD with just one row per combination.

Comment: Looks like XY problem. What is the purpose of the query?

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by `value`.  Hence, the standard deviation is not defined.  I think you intend for the subquery to be:

```
select Name, Report_Date,
       Dense_Rank() Over (Order by Report_Date DESC) as Dno,
       (AVG(value) + 3 * STDEV(value)) as UpperLimit,
       (AVG(value) + 3 * STDEV(value)) * 0.85 as Limit 
from #Temp1 
group by Name, Report_date
```